# Does the word candidate have to refer to a person?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, formality

I was helping a friend create a motivational letter for a scholarship and I wrote a sentence in the lines of: "(...), which would qualify **my project** as a **candidate** for the Program".

We changed this because my friend suggested the word candidate can only refer to a person. Notably the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate) dictionary lists only the uses that refer to people.

However lately I've seen a few uses of the word when refering to objects, primarly in tech articles. So can this word be used in a broader sense?

Comment: Is this question is a  good candidate for this site?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/candidate

Comment: Yes, every time you download a release candidate from Firefox or Apple or Microsoft, they deliver an actual human being that then lives inside your machine.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - That's who's been eating my M&Ms!!

Comment: Candidate is a good candidate for that sentence!

Comment: Since Merriam-Webster is active on Twitter, I went ahead and tweeted a link to this discussion to their account. https://twitter.com/RotationlSymtry/status/1031914677809434626

Comment: Why do you capitalise *program*?

Comment: @Kris Is it not? The StackExchange guidelines are a bit overwhelming, but I don't see what is wrong with the question. Would you mind explaining? However I'm sorry if my question goes below the quality of the site's content.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The word Program is part of the name of the scholarship, so we were referencing the name, rather than describing the scholarship as a program. I shouldn't have capitalized it here and maybe capitalizing it in the letter was a mistake as well.

Comment: @Lurco I did not say it is not, nor do I necessarily think so. That comment was a kind of pun -- see the up votes it received. So, have a good laugh.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/candidate) definition 4 has the following (my emphasis):

> A candidate is a person **or thing** that is regarded as being suitable for a particular purpose or as being likely to do or be a particular thing.

I use 'candidate' a lot in this sense, drawing up lists of software bug fixes to be considered for inclusion in a new release.

Comment: It's interesting that M-W only considers 'candidate' applying to a person though. Oxford, Cambridge and Collins (cited above)  all have "person or thing" in their definitions. Perhaps because of the overwhelming use of 'candidate' in its application to American politics compared with other uses in AM-E?

Comment: It could simply be a matter of Collins considering candidate (when used for a thing) as a figurative (loose) usage, rather than a strictly defined one. People often use figurative or loose language (my computer died/a loud color/...) and its particular meaning (when different from the literal meaning) doesn't always make it into the dictionary.

Comment: "Release candidate" is a commonly used term for a new version of software, which still has to be tested but if it passes the tests, would actually become a new release.

Comment: I think this M-W definition covers the non-person case: "one likely or suited to undergo or be chosen for something specified [, e.g.,] a candidate for surgery". The word "one" in this sense can refer to a thing rather than a person.

Comment: @MarkFoskey I agree, but the fact that all of the examples they provide are of people is misleading.

Answer (score 8):

The use of *candidate* for a project is, I believe, supported by all dictionaries. The difference between [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate) and [Oxford's](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/candidate) or [Collins'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/candidate) wording is no coincidence:

> **one** likely or suited to undergo or be chosen for something specified

vs.

> A **person or thing** ...

If we look up [*one*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one) we find, among others:

> a certain indefinitely indicated **person or thing**.

It's simply that "one that ..." can be a person or thing; the quoted dictionaries agree, but M-W is more concise.

This is corroborated by M-W's [entry for victim:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/victim)

> **one** that is acted on and usually adversely affected by a force or agent: **the schools** are victims of the social system

Answer (score 3):

No, it can refer to any noun. If you want to further clarify,  you can use candidate as an adjective: "...which would qualify (project name) as a candidate project for the program."

Comment: I like the adjective idea, it sounds elegant.